# Filter Array of objects with nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, javascript-objects

so I am trying to set up a nested filter on an array of objects.
The thing is that the filter is applied inside the object on a key that is another array of objects.

here is the code:

```
const items = [
  { name: "123", id: 1, value:  true, arr: [{ id: 1 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 2 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 3 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 4 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 5 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 6 }] },
];

const newArray = items.filter((objects) => {
  objects.arr.filter((item) => {
    if (item.id === 2) {
      return objects;
    }
     
  });
});
console.log(newArray);
```

I 'm not sure where to put the return because in this situation i just get an empty array.

Comment: Alex, I added an answer. I hope it helps as per the problem statement you have.

Comment: It sure did. managed to fix my issue, thanks to you and everyone else who answered! :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to check the nested array contains the wanted `id` and return the result to the filter method.

```js
const
    items = [{ name: "123", id: 1, value: true, arr: [{ id: 1 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 2 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 3 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 4 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 5 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 6 }] }],
    result = items.filter(({ arr }) => arr.some(({ id }) => id === 2));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if current `arr` has an element with `id` equal to 2:

```js
const items = [ { name: "123", id: 1, value:  true, arr: [{ id: 1 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 2 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 3 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 4 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 5 }] }, { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 6 }] } ];

const newArray = items.filter(({ arr = [] }) => 
  arr.some(({ id }) => id === 2)
);

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you contains only one `object` in `arr` then you can access this object by using `[0]` index.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const items = [
  { name: "123", id: 1, value:  true, arr: [{ id: 1 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 2 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 3 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 4 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 5 }] },
  { name: "456", id: 2, value: false, arr: [{ id: 6 }] },
];

const newArray = items.filter((obj) => {
    if (obj.arr[0].id === 2) {
    return obj;
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

I answered you as per the issue you are facing but if you have multiple objects in your `arr` then you can go ahead with [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method as suggested by other answers.