# Filter array of objects inside array of objects by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I have array of objects (allItems) with different properties (countries, name). Countries is array inside object that I need to filter by searchByCountry parameter which is just a name (string) of country e.g. 'Germany'.

```
var allItems = [{
  name: 'Item1',
  countries: [
      {label: 'Argentina', TermGuid: 'abc'},
      {label: 'Germany', TermGuid: 'abc'},
      {label: 'Bosnia', TermGuid: 'abc'},
      {label: 'France', TermGuid: 'abc'},
      {label: 'UK', TermGuid: 'abc'}
    ]
  },
  {
   name: 'Item2',
   countries: [
    {label: 'Argentina', TermGuid: 'abc'}
   ]
  },
  {
   name: 'Item3',
   countries: [
    {label: 'Bosnia', TermGuid: 'abc'}
   ]
  },
  {
   name: 'Item4',
   countries: [
    {label: 'All', TermGuid: 'abc'}
   ]
  }
]

    
var searchByCountry = 'Bosnia';
```

So expected output for 'Bosnia' would be:

```
var allItems = [{
  name: 'Item1',
  countries: [
      {label: 'Argentina', TermGuid: 'abc'},
      {label: 'Germany', TermGuid: 'abc'},
      {label: 'Bosnia', TermGuid: 'abc'},
      {label: 'France', TermGuid: 'abc'},
      {label: 'UK', TermGuid: 'abc'}
    ]
  },
  {
   name: 'Item3',
   countries: [
    {label: 'Bosnia', TermGuid: 'abc'}
   ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far and what specifically you're struggling with in your attempt?

Comment: using `filter` and `some`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter nested array in object array by array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650390/filter-nested-array-in-object-array-by-array-of-values)

Comment: also [Filter Array of objects with nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71183468/filter-array-of-objects-with-nested-array)

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using array filter and some method, this should do the trick:

```js
var allItems = [{
    name: 'Item1',
    countries: [{
        label: 'Argentina',
        TermGuid: 'abc'
      },
      {
        label: 'Germany',
        TermGuid: 'abc'
      },
      {
        label: 'Bosnia',
        TermGuid: 'abc'
      },
      {
        label: 'France',
        TermGuid: 'abc'
      },
      {
        label: 'UK',
        TermGuid: 'abc'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Item2',
    countries: [{
      label: 'Argentina',
      TermGuid: 'abc'
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'Item3',
    countries: [{
      label: 'Bosnia',
      TermGuid: 'abc'
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'Item4',
    countries: [{
      label: 'All',
      TermGuid: 'abc'
    }]
  }
]


var searchByCountry = 'Bosnia';

const filtered = allItems.filter(item => item.countries.some(country => country.label === searchByCountry))

console.log(filtered)
```